# Using import to get css files in ES6 (java script 6)

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6

I saw the next ES6 code:

```
import '../node_modules/spectre.css/dist/spectre.min.css';  
import './styles.css';
```

what's the meaning of using    .    ..    ...    ....
just after

```
import '
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with CSS or JavaScript for that matter. See [What means the dots on a path?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249039)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dots indicate which directory you're starting from.

`./index.js` looks for index.js in the current directory.
`../index.js` looks for index.js inside the parent directory.

Comment: and if used  ...  dots will it mean the parent of the parent folder?

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga: No. `../../` is the parent parent folder.